# Ambiguous overload for ‘operator>>’ in ‘std::cin >>'

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading, istream

I'm having an issue trying to get some code for an assignment to compile. I've looked at similar issues (even ones that seem to be the same exact assignment), but none of the solutions worked.

my header file: 'complex.h':

```
#ifndef COMPLEX_H_INCLUDED
#define COMPLEX_H_INCLUDED
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

class Complex
{
public:
    // Consructors:
    Complex();
    Complex(double);
    Complex(double, double);

    // Operational Overloads:
    const bool operator == (const Complex&);
    const Complex operator + (const Complex&);
    const Complex operator + (const double&);
    const Complex operator - (const Complex&);
    const Complex operator - (const double&);
    const Complex operator * (const Complex&);
    const Complex operator * (const double&);
    friend ostream& operator << (ostream&, const Complex&);
    friend istream& operator >> (istream&, Complex&);

private:
    double real;
    double imaginary;
};

#endif // COMPLEX_H_INCLUDED
```

My implementation code, 'complex.cpp':

```
#include "complex.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

/****************************************************************************
 *   Constructor ()                                                         *
 ****************************************************************************/
inline Complex::Complex(){
real = 0;
    imaginary = 0;
}

/****************************************************************************
 *   Constructor (double)                                                   *
 ****************************************************************************/
 inline Complex::Complex(double realPart)
             :real(realPart)
{
    imaginary = 0;
}

/****************************************************************************
 *   Constructor (double, double)                                           *
 ****************************************************************************/
inline Complex::Complex(double realPart, double imaginaryPart)
            :real(realPart), imaginary(imaginaryPart)
{}

/****************************************************************************
 *  Operator '==' -- Compares two Complex objects                           *
 *              Returns:                                                    *
 *                -- True if their real and imaginary values are equal      *
 *                -- False otherwise                                        *
 ****************************************************************************/
inline const bool Complex::operator == (const Complex& rhs)
{
    return ((this->real == rhs.real)  && (this->imaginary == rhs.imaginary));
}

/****************************************************************************
 *  Operator '+' -- Adds two Complex objects                                *
 *              Returns:                                                    *
 *                -- The new Complex object                                 *
 ****************************************************************************/
inline const Complex Complex::operator + (const Complex& rhs)
{
    return (Complex((this->real + rhs.real), (this->imaginary + rhs.imaginary)));
}

/****************************************************************************
 *  Operator '+' -- Adds a real number to the Complex object                *
 *              Returns:                                                    *
 *                -- The new Complex object                                 *
 ****************************************************************************/
inline const Complex Complex::operator+(const double& rhs)
{
    return Complex((this->real + rhs), this->imaginary);
}

/****************************************************************************
 *  Operator '-' -- Subtracts the number of another Complex object          *
 *              Returns:                                                    *
 *                -- The new Complex object                                 *
 ****************************************************************************/
inline const Complex Complex::operator - (const Complex& rhs)
{
    return (Complex((this->real - rhs.real), (this->imaginary - rhs.imaginary)));
}

/****************************************************************************
 *  Operator '-' -- Subtracts a real number from the Complex object         *
 *              Returns:                                                    *
 *                -- The new Complex object                                 *
 ****************************************************************************/
inline const Complex Complex::operator-(const double& rhs)
{
    return Complex((this->real - rhs), this->imaginary);
}

/****************************************************************************
 *  Operator '*' -- Multiplies together two Complex objects                 *
 *              Returns:                                                    *
 *                -- The new Complex object                                 *
 ****************************************************************************/
inline const Complex Complex::operator * (const Complex& rhs)
{
    return (Complex((this->real * rhs.real) - (this->imaginary * rhs.imaginary), (this->real * rhs.imaginary) + (this->imaginary * rhs.real)));
}

/****************************************************************************
 *  Operator '*' -- Mutltiplies the Complex object by a real number         *
 *              Returns:                                                    *
 *                -- The new Complex object                                 *
 ****************************************************************************/
inline const Complex Complex::operator * (const double& rhs)
{
    return Complex((this->real * rhs), (this->imaginary * rhs));
}

/****************************************************************************
 *  Operator '<<' -- Outputs the Complex object in a comprehensive format   *
 *              Returns:                                                    *
 *                -- A reference to the ostream                             *
 ****************************************************************************/
ostream& operator <<(ostream& out, const Complex& comp)
{
    if(comp.real != 0)
    {
        out << comp.real;

        if(comp.imaginary > 0)
            out << " + ";
        else if (comp.imaginary < 0)
            out << " - ";
    }

    if(comp.imaginary != 0)
        out << comp.imaginary << "i";

    return out;
}

/****************************************************************************
 *  Operator '>>' -- Takes in a Complex object from the user                *
 *              Returns:                                                    *
 *                -- A reference to the istream                             *
 ****************************************************************************/
istream& operator >>(istream& in, Complex& comp)
{
    char sign; //Used to store input when looking for mathematical operators
    bool neg = false; //Stores whether or not any input values are <0

    // Checks for a negative value for the real
    sign = std::cin.peek();
    if(sign == '-'){
        neg = true;
        std::cin.ignore(1,'-');
    }

    in >> comp.real;

    //Negates the real value if necessary
    if(neg){
        comp.real = -comp.real;
        neg = false;
    }

    //Looks for the + or - operator, accounting for possible variations in whitespacing and hazardous input.
    do{
        in >> sign;
    }while (sign == ' ');

    if (sign == '-')
        neg = true;
    else if (sign != '+'){
        cout << "You did not properly format the input of a complex number. \nPlease use the format: 'a+bi' where 'a' is the real number, and 'b' is the imaginary number." << endl;
        cout << "The program is currently shutting down.";
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    sign = std::cin.peek();

    while(sign == ' ')
        in >> sign;

    in >> comp.imaginary;

    if(neg)
        comp.imaginary = -comp.imaginary;
}
```

And final class which implements complex.cpp:

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include "complex.cpp"

 using namespace std;

 int main()
 {
     Complex aComplex();

     cout << "Please enter a complex number, in the form of 'a+bi', where 'a' is a real number and 'b' the imaginary number." << endl;
     cin >> aComplex;

     cout << "You entered the value: " << aComplex << endl;

     return 0;
 }
```

When I try to build the code, I get the error:

```
.../Complex/main.cpp|12|error: ambiguous overload for ‘operator>>’ in ‘std::cin >> aComplex'`
```

Anyone have any ideas? (I am using Code::Blocks 12.11 and using Ubuntu 13.04, if that helps.)

Comment: `Complex aComplex();` - this defines a function, not a variable...

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's more to that error message. What are the candidates functions?

Comment: `using namespace std;` in a header will net you 10% of the people willing to use it.

Comment: Fun fact: If you compile your program with clang instead of gcc, you will get a warning: empty parentheses interpreted as a function declaration
      [-Wvexing-parse]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `aComplex` is declared as a function! You probably meant to write one of the following:

```
Complex aComplex;
Complex bComplex = Complex();
Complex cComplex{};
```

Look for " most vexing parse" to get an explanation of why your `aComplex` is a function declaration.

Comment: Wow, I've banging my head against the wall for hours, and the issue was such an easy fix...

Answer (score 0):

```
Complex aComplex();
```

This doesn't call the constructor of `Complex`, it creates the people of a function taking zero arguments and returning an object of type `Complex`. The empty parenthesis should be removed if you want to instantiate an object:

```
Complex aComplex;
```